# How do I get information for all the versions of a particular package in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I want to get information related to all the versions of a package from its first version to the current version for Ubuntu.

I can tap into the info using apt or apt-cache, but it gives info only for the current package version.

Maybe, I should first get a list of the package's versions and then try getting info for each of them at once. But how to do this using the package-manager or is there some other way for getting all the versions' info at once?

Comment: What information are you looking for, for each released version?

Comment: Source, Version number, homepage, maintainer, architecture etc. basically all info provided by apt-cache search or apt search. I know most will be the same for all versions. But atleast version number will be different in all versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of tools available to view information about package versions available in Ubuntu (or any Debian derivative).

- `apt changelog` will show the list of changes made to a given package, going back to either the creation of the changelog or the introduction of the package in Debian.
- `rmadison` (from the `devscripts` package) will show the currently-available versions across all available repositories; for example

  ```
  $ rmadison -u ubuntu gcc
  gcc | 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5   | precise         | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
  gcc | 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6   | trusty          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
  gcc | 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1   | xenial          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
  gcc | 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2   | bionic          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
  gcc | 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 | bionic-security | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
  gcc | 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 | bionic-updates  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
  gcc | 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2   | focal           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
  gcc | 4:10.2.0-1ubuntu1  | groovy          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
  gcc | 4:10.2.0-1ubuntu1  | hirsute         | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
  ```
- For Ubuntu specifically, Launchpad provides lots of information on packages, including everything shown above (see [the corresponding `gcc-defaults` information](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults)); there’s [a Debian equivalent](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gcc-defaults) too.

To see the homepage, maintainer etc. across all published versions, you’ll have to look at the history of the `debian/control` file in the packages’ source repositories (if any), or failing that, in the package archives. You’ll be able to find all that from the package trackers above (Launchpad etc.), or using `debcheckout` (from the `devscripts` package) for packages with a published repository.

Many other distributions have similar tools and/or sites.

Comment: Isn't `apt-cache madison <packagename>` doing the same? I guess that only shows stuff for my local sources?

Comment: @Panki `apt-cache madison` emulates `madison`’s output, using the information it has (locally). So it’s not the same as `rmadison`, it won’t show all the information that’s available in the remote database.

Answer (score 0):

rmadison is what you may want:

```
# apt install devscripts
<...>

# rmadison sudo
sudo       | 1.8.10p3-1+deb8u5   | oldoldstable       | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386
sudo       | 1.8.19p1-2.1+deb9u2 | oldstable          | source, amd64, arm64, armel, armhf, i386, mips, mips64el, mipsel, ppc64el, s390x
sudo       | 1.8.19p1-2.1+deb9u2 | oldstable-debug    | source
sudo       | 1.8.27-1+deb10u3    | stable             | source, amd64, arm64, armel, armhf, i386, mips, mips64el, mipsel, ppc64el, s390x
sudo       | 1.8.27-1+deb10u3    | stable-debug       | source
sudo       | 1.9.5p2-3           | testing            | source, amd64, arm64, armel, armhf, i386, mips64el, mipsel, ppc64el, s390x
sudo       | 1.9.5p2-3           | unstable           | source, amd64, arm64, armel, armhf, i386, mips64el, mipsel, ppc64el, s390x
sudo       | 1.9.5p2-3           | unstable-debug     | source
sudo       | 1.9.6-1~exp2        | experimental       | source, amd64, arm64, armel, armhf, i386, mips64el, mipsel, ppc64el, s390x
sudo       | 1.9.6-1~exp2        | experimental-debug | source
```